# Git rebase workflow issues

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

There are many posts / questions / blogs about git rebase workflow.  The following is what I understood and performed:

Rebase the local master to upstream

```
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

Rebase the fork master to upstream

```
git push origin +master
```

So far so good ..
Now: attempt to Rebase the local branch to local master

```
git checkout strlen
git rebase -i HEAD~50  
# In the interactive I do a bunch of fixups and move the latest branch commit to the top
```

Some merge conflicts: so let us try to resolve them
git status

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/SqlParser.scala
#   both modified:      sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLQuerySuite.scala
#   both modified:      sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveQl.scala
```

So let's do the manual merge and then add them:

```
meld sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/SqlParser.scala
meld sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLQuerySuite.scala
meld  sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveQl.scala
git add -a
git rebase -i --continue
```

Now here is the spot I get confused:  the rebase now still complains about the same three files requiring a merge. But now it shows the merge conflict is due to an *earlier commit on the same branch (strlen)*.   But why?   The rebase should have only had ONE merge conflict - tops - per file. Why are multiple merge conflicts happening on the *same* files?

Comment: The `-i` flag that you're using in the rebase command makes it an interactive rebase. Judging from your question that's not what you want.

Comment: Short not-quite-answer: rebase copies commits one at a time; a merge conflict in an "early" commit often remains a conflict in later commits.  It's quite common to have conflicts persist all throughout.  However, if you set `git rerere` (reuse recorded resolution), that often automates the fixing-up.

Comment: @PatrikOldsberg  I have updated the OP to describe how I am using (and do want) rebase -i.

Comment: @torek My concern is that there are a half dozen commits in my branch - all of which touch the same set of files. The final commit has the .. well.. final version. That is what I want. Clearly going through 6 merges means I did something wrong in my process - we should instead be going directly to the end result.

Comment: @torek The rerere looks interesting regardless: I am going to do "git config --global rerere.enabled true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the workflow a bit to the following:

git pull --rebase origin mybranch

git rebase --continue

git push -f origin mybranch